# Turn on or turn off SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a simple MVC app which displays a single table changes in the db using SignalR.
Followed the sample [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5) with some minor changes and it works.

Currently there are only inserts so the web page shows the records.
I wanted to know if there was a way, like a switch, that can activate or de-activate the SignalR code.
Example:
There will be a checkbox which will enable or disable the showing of real time results.

Regards.

Comment: Yes there is. It is called "if"

Comment: What have you tried? If you've managed to implement SignalR to display real time table changes, it's likely that you have the skill set to do this. Maybe start with creating a checkbox. Then add some JavaScript that runs when the checkbox is selected or unselected that enables or disables the SignalR connection?